# Repair boot after update from 13.10 to 14.04 LTS

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, 14.04

I have an Ubuntu server that's been around for some time and has gone through several upgrades without any major problems. However, after the last upgrade - from 13.10 to 14.04 - the system simply refuses to boot up again. I get a message somewhere along the lines of:

"Disk boot failure. Insert system disc and try again."

I tried using Boot-Repair, stepping through the instructions, but it encountered an error. Hoping for some help I post the url to the report here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7545663/

At the end of the report it says "Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdg1/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file!" but I can't find in the BIOS how to do that. I have never had to do that before and its been running like clock for years until now.

Please tell me if there is need of any further information from my part and thanks in advance for any help I may get.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have it solved after more than a month... The following worked for me:

- Try to turn-off EFI (secure) boot in BIOS and try it again.
- Then use a recovery DVD (or a GParted CD, for example).
- Mount the partition containing /boot directory (e.g. /dev/sda2).
- Use "grub-install" and install it onto a MBR of your HDD - you will have to tell it where the /boot is. I also had to use the -force option.

After that the 14.04 booted up normally.